# Who is Robertson?

Tags: predestination

The first time I watched *Predestination* I believed that a twist would be that Robertson would also turn out to be the same person as Jane/John.

However no clue is given to his identity. The Fizzle Bomber says at the end however:

> We're just puppets. **We are Robertson.**
>   He set the whole thing up.
>   He played us for fools.
>   He's laying out the dominoes.
>   You know, we're just watching it fall.

What does he mean by that line?
Is there any clue/theory as to who Robertson is?

Comment: Good question. I suspect that "*no clue is given to his identity*" is precisely who he is...

Comment: But at the same time, he does seem to important to not be someone special.

Comment: Relevant: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28403/who-is-mr-robertson

Answer (score 3):

> > We're just puppets. We are Robertson. He set the whole thing up.
>
> What does he mean by that line?

It is difficult, watching a movie where

> one person is most of the characters

to not interpret that line as meaning they're the same person.  However, I think a less literal interpretation applies - "We are Robertson" simply means "We're just puppets," e.g., we're dancing on his strings, we are the avatar that effects the changes he wishes to see in the world, we are reduced to carrying out his plans whether intentionally or unintentionally.

From what I saw in the film, and the [link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28403/who-is-mr-robertson) @FuzzyBoots provided in the comments seems to concur, Mr. Robertson is not another incarnation of Jane/John.